# How to post data from Defaul.aspx to another aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just building a practice site for learning purpose. below is my Default.aspx page using twiter bootstrap. Note controls here are HTML not asp.net controls.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>My Practice Website</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <form method="post" runat="server" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtLName">First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtFName" name="txtFName" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtUName">Username</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                    <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtUName" name="txtUName" placeholder="Enter User Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input type="password" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Enter Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtLName">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtLName" name="txtLName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input type="password" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtConfirmPassword" name="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="Enter Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <button type="submit" runat="server" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" onserverclick="btnSubmit_click" >
                                <span>Submit</span>
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
                            </button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want tp post this form data into another page let say User.aspx. How to do that from Code behind? anyone please.

Comment: Several ways, sessions, querystrings, but the best way to do this here is save it in a database.

Comment: hello thank you for the quick reponce, can you please give me some sample code. @prospector

Comment: If you are learning ASP.NET, I would recommend learning MVC over WebForms. This is a trivial task in MVC.

Comment: @ImdadAli, please see my answer I have given you a sample code for your form and also since there is no ASP.NET control, why are you trying to write the `runat="server"` attribute there? There is no need for that.

Comment: yeah thats really my second aim but i want to have some basic idea of web form. Actally my friend is an experience Php developer, he is giving me a start. he told to build a html page, i have done that now he is saying to post the data into another page in asp.net. As he is Php developer he don't know how to do that in asp, i tried alot of searching but em not able to do this simple task. One other thing i have searched for MVC tutorials, its all in Razor markup, can you suggest some MVC tutorial using aspx markup.

Comment: Web Forms and other things (HTML markup) are really very different things and you should know that. Sending the data to the other pages are basic and default HTML things, form's action attribute is an HTML thing, ASP.NET doesn't really much work in that context, anyways the Request is an ASP.NET property. As already said, leave Web Forms and learn the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your HTML controls have the `runat` attribute set to `server`, you can grab their values in code behind. You may want something like this:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; } 
    // And so on and so forth for the other properties to save.
}

protected void btnSubmit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    MyData md = new MyData();
    md.FirstName = txtFName.Value;
    md.UserName = txtUName.Value;
    // And so on and so forth for the other controls.

    Session["MyData"] = md;  
}
```

In the other page:

```
MyData md = (MyData)Session["MyData"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can post it to the second page, try change the form element's markup to this one,

```
<form method="post" action="~/User.aspx">
```

Note that there is no need for the `runat="server"` attribute for a plain HTML element. After that, you can collect the data passed by the user on the User.aspx page, by getting the objects like this,

```
if(IsPost) {
    // Post Request
    var txtFName = Request["txtFName"];
    // and so on...
}
```

.. this would be enough to collect the data from one page, to another page.

Comment: Hello Afzal Ahmad Zeeshan bro, thank you for the reply but there is an error on if(IsPost) that IsPost doesn't exist in the current context. Why is that?

Comment: Hey, that was a property inside ASP.NET Web Pages framework, and is available inside System.Web.Helpers namespace. If you're not using it, then you'll get this error. For more on this property please see this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.ispost(v=vs.111).aspx